# How to equal two strings case sensitively in Linq to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, case-sensitive

How to equal two strings case sensitively in Linq to SQL (in a where query)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do it solely within LINQ to SQL. From the documentation:

> Unsupported System.String Methods in
>   General
>
> Queries do not account for SQL Server
>   collations that might be in effect on
>   the server, and therefore will provide
>   culture-sensitive, case-insensitive
>   comparisons by default. This behavior
>   differs from the default,
>   case-sensitive semantics of the .NET
>   Framework.

The way to do it is in your own query where you specify the collation:

```
Select...
From Table
Where Column = "Value" COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```

Note that the collation I'm providing specifies a case-sensitive match (CS).

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to make the field in question case-sensitive in SQL Server (or whatever DBMS you use). If you use SQL Server, look for the Collation field property, in there you can set case sensitivity.

Answer (score 2):

How to equal two strings case sensitively in Linq to SQL (in a where query)?

```
Select * from tblemp Where empname='nAveen' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS
```