# String Comparsion in ASP.net (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, string-comparison

I'm writing Android application that connect with ASP.net web service (C#,3.5)

android Application send "Sign in" information of the user to web service to verify that if the user is registered or not.

here is the `[WebMethod]` which receive the request :

```
[WebMethod]
public SigninPerson signin(SigninPerson SIPerson)
{
    SigninPerson Temp = new SigninPerson(0, "", "", "", "");
    LinqToSQLDataContext DataBase = new LinqToSQLDataContext();
    var Person = (from a in DataBase.Persons
                  where a.Email == SIPerson.E_Mail &&
                      a.Password.Equals(SIPerson.Password,StringComparison.Ordinal)
                  select new SigninPerson
                  {
                      Person_Id = a.Person_Id,
                      F_Name = a.First_Name,
                      L_Name = a.Last_Name,
                      E_Mail = a.Email,
                      Password = a.Password
                  });
    if (Person.Any() == true)
    {
        Temp = Person.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return Temp;
}
```

`SigninPerson` is a class which hold user information like First Name, Last Name , Password....

the problem is in the password comparison. it accepted all the cases

for example:

if the password for somebody which stored in DataBase is "ABD", and the user entered "abd"
as password , the application accepted it! (not Case sensitive !!!)

how to solve this problem?

Comment: See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc165449.aspx)

Comment: @Alex: It's still a bit odd though, since StringComparison.Ordinal should be case sensitive (otherwise, he should've used StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase).

Comment: The issue here is that the SQL Server doesn't do an ordinal comparison.

Comment: Yes, neoistheone is completely right.

Comment: You should be hashing passwords, not storing them in plain text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your LINQ to this:

```
var Person = (from a in DataBase.Persons
              where a.Email == SIPerson.E_Mail
              select new SigninPerson
              {
                  Person_Id = a.Person_Id,
                  F_Name = a.First_Name,
                  L_Name = a.Last_Name,
                  E_Mail = a.Email,
                  Password = a.Password
              })
              .ToList()
              .Where(sp => sp.Password.Equals(SIPerson.Password));
```

This will **force** the string comparison to occur client-side, via the .NET framework, instead of server-side on the SQL Server.

---

As andleer stated, there is another approach that may be more efficient. Now, in practice it's unlikely you'd see this, but it's a good habit to get into. You could actually do this:

```
var Person = (from a in DataBase.Persons
              where a.Email == SIPerson.E_Mail
              select new SigninPerson
              {
                  Person_Id = a.Person_Id,
                  F_Name = a.First_Name,
                  L_Name = a.Last_Name,
                  E_Mail = a.Email,
                  Password = a.Password
              })
              .Take(1)
              .AsEnumerable()
              .Where(sp => sp.Password.Equals(SIPerson.Password));
```

This **should** ensure that it would never return all the rows, but just 1. Again, in this actual case it's probably not that relevant because there would almost certainly only ever be one - but it's a nice thought to add and worth noting.

Comment: Simple. Nice solution.

Comment: Actually an even better solution: instead of `ToList()`, `.Take(1).AsEnumerable()`. If the query matches on 1000 records, you only need to know about none or one to satisfy the `Any()` condition.

Comment: @andleer: If it matches more than one record then there is quite a serious logic problem. I expect Email is meant to be unique

Comment: @neoistheone Good solution but in the case where it is important to avoid returning more results than is necessary, then it's worth highlighting that you can make the column case sensitive in the database.

Comment: @neoistheone it works locally , but when I upload my project to smarterasp.net the problem return :( why ?

Comment: @MGCR7, which version of the code did you use? My first approach or the second? Further, what version of the .NET framework is installed on `smarterasp.net`? Are they using the same one you have?

Comment: @neoistheone I used your first approach, and `smarterasp.net` using 4.X framework library.

Comment: @MGCR7, I'm not sure. I'll have to think about that. But it feels to me right now like the app pool might need recycled.

Comment: @neoistheone I tried to remove one of the Web Methods from the web service, when I refresh the site, the Web method which I removed still appear in the Web methods list !!!

Comment: @MGCR7, yeah, just as I suspected. There is something wrong with their propagation. It's probably time to contact their support.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that SQL will not perform case sensitive matches unless it has been configured to do so, [see here for more information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600932/how-to-equal-two-strings-case-sensitively-in-linq-to-sql).

Alternatively, you can just do the check via code after you have got your match:

Instead of `if (Person.Any())`, use this:

```
var first = Person.FirstOrDefault();
if (first != null && first.Password == SIPerson.Password)
{
    Temp = first;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but your premise is not always correct. SQL performs case comparisons based on the collation option when it was configured. It may or may not be case sensitive. Also, collation can be set at the server, database or column level.

Comment: @andleer: Yeah, I said that, I didn't use the word "collation" but that is described in the link I posted. `"It does seem that you can set certain fields to be handled case-senstively"` = change the collation, as described in link